# Jquery get and set css attribute of some part of html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, editor

I'm writing an html editor control.
I want to change css attributes of selected text of the content.
I get the selectedcontent by  window.getSelection();
What is the best way to make bold selected text, and to understand selected text is bold then to make it normal.
Replace with required tags doesn't work. Since similar texts can be in content.
It looks quite complicated to me.
I'm looking for the best practise to do it.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a 3rd party editor, unless you want something very basic and simple.

Comment: for making text bold add `<strong>` tag on that selected text and to understand selected text is bold you can check for `<strong>`. does this make sense  ?

Comment: Try to avoid asking for *"the best way"* way to do things for your question might be flagged as "opinion based"

Comment: @Aabid let's say my text something like  'aaa bbb aa bbbb cccc' and i wanted to make bold second bbb section and wanted to unbold later, how can i do that? how do i understand which bbb?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 i mean best practise for this problem.

Comment: @Archer yes it will be simple and customized for us. Do you have a suggesation for it?

Comment: when you want to do any operation on text you need to select it and after getting selected you can check of `<strong>` tag

Comment: this is where i'm stuck already. I got the selected text but where is the selected text belong if there are many of occurence! @Aabid

Comment: Look at [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/)  but I really recommend searching for a complete 3rd party editor solution, rather than writing your own.

Comment: I will consider @Archer , thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample snippet

You can make bold as selected text via "document.execCommand('bold');"

### Html

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="textEditor">Text1.
    Text2.
    Text3.
    Text4.
    Hi, this is text of some kind
Lorem ipsum...
</div>
```

### Jquery

> 1. Catch selection change event by jquery-selectionchange event.
> 2. Make bold and normal by document.execCommand('bold');

```
 $(document).on('selectionchange', function(e) { 
            document.execCommand('bold');
    });
```

### JsFIddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XCb95/132/

Comment: This is exactly What I'm looking for.